# Why did this still happen in the ending of USS Callister?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, black-mirror

*This post is about S04E01 of Black Mirror, titled [USS Callister](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5710974/)*.

Half way through the episode, it was established that the Christmas update patch was the wormhole that Cole saw when she was looking through the window, and that, by flying through the wormhole, the ship would run into the system firewall, causing the rogue code to be deleted (and thus freeing them from Daly).

When racing to the wormhole, it was mentioned that the wormhole was getting *smaller* in size, and is the reason why they took the increased chance by flying through the asteroid belt.

Once the crew reached the black hole, the USS Callister successfully made it through, *but not Daly*. Regardless of this, according to Kabir, Daly's rogue game code still got deleted, and his controls were disabled.

**If Daly didn't go through the wormhole and run into the firewall, why did his code still get deleted?**

[image]

Comment: No, they flew through the hole to escape the secluded environment they were trapped in.

Comment: I wouldn't read to much into it - all these black mirror episodes focus more on how bad things can go with technology, not so much on making it behave accurately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daly's rogue code isn't segmented into his ship + his avatar vs the USS Callister--it's the entire "Space Fleet" mod. His computer was connected to the network during the update, but not detected; however, when the USS Callister flew through the wormhole, it crossed the firewall and the existence of the mod as a whole became apparent to the main system. Therefore, the game did what it was designed to do when detecting that someone added an illegal mod--deleted it.

It's worth pointing out that the crew /thought/ that flying through the wormhole would delete their ship, but they were wrong--all it did was take them into the "main game" and make the existence of the mod visible.

So Daly's game is networked -> update starts -> Callister flies through the update wormhole -> main servers detect illegal mod -> entire illegal mod is deleted.